# How to fetch lazy collection in QueryDSL 4

Tags: spring-boot, jpql, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have a following problem with executing quite simple query with querydsl. Imagine that we have two entities:

CAR ----< OWNERS

I would like to execute query which returns all cars and fetches all its owners which are mapped lazily. In other words, I would like to fetch those to be used outside of transaction.

My query looks like:

```
List<Car> cars = new JPAQuery<Car>(em)
                    .select(car).from(car)
                    .leftJoin(car.owners, owner)
                    .where(car.make.eq(make))
                    .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, car.id))
                    .distinct()
                    .fetch();
```

Similar query worked fine in QueryDSL 3, but after upgrade to 4 I am getting LazyInitializationException, which means that 'owners' are not fetched properly. Could you please shed some light on how to solve this problem?

For example when I write this query manually it works completely fine:

```
List<Car> cars = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Car c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.owners WHERE c.make = :make ORDER BY c.id ASC")
            .setParameter("make", make).getResultList();
```

I am using spring-boot 2 with querydsl 4.1.4

BTW, query which worked fine in querydsl 3

```
List<Car> car = new JPAQuery(em)
                .from(car)
                .leftJoin(car.owners)
                .fetch()
                .distinct()
                .where(car.make.eq(make))
                .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, car.id))
                .list(car);
```

Answer (score 6):

after multiple attempts I have found a solution, here is the code:

```
new JPAQuery<Car>(em)
           .select(car)
           .distinct()
           .from(car)
           .leftJoin(car.owners, owner).fetchJoin()
           .where(car.make.eq(make))
           .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, car.id))
           .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i had to change `new JPAQuery(em)` to `new JPAQuery<Foo>(em)`